# iOS using sockets to talk to other apps

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, cordova

Is it possible to have 2 apps on 1 iPhone/iPad talk to another via sockets?  For example The main app is phonegap app that just displays data and when the user clicks the print button, the 1st app sends data to the 2nd (2nd app stays in the background, I guess it is a service), it (the 2nd app) then sends that data to a printer that it knows how to talk to whether that is via a webservice call or something else.

From my scan of the docs and other questions it seems the custom URL is one way to make the apps talk, but I want the receiver app to stay in the background.  So do I have to use a server/client approach to this?  Is that possible.

Comment: y specifically sockets ? u can try to put that file in some common server repo and then send a push notification to the other app .

Comment: It needs to be fast, and network may be restricted to a LAN/WAN.

Comment: you have a problems which threatens sandboxing environment. There is not direct way you can do this but check this out http://blog.studywiz.com/2011/02/08/ipads-webdav-and-elockers/ . WebDav is a server used to exchange remote files you can do this with local too. The only thing you need is the other app to know the port address which you can do by a common server repo. The files would be transferred locally but metadata is exchanged via common server. I don't know if there is a better alternative to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can.  Just make sure your 2nd app - the background app is conformed to Apple's requirement to run in background modes.  You can also use Bonjour to aid in discovery or just pre-selected a port and make other apps aware of it value.

Comment: So using sockets is the best way to do this app to app communication?

Comment: In your scenario, it looks like this probably is better than custom URL scheme.  Assuming that you can get background app to print.  One additional benefit is that other local connected wifi iDevices can also submit a print job.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no socket-based interprocess communication between apps on an iPhone, nor is there any concept of apps as background services. Using custom URLs to launch another app is the only direct method of communication between apps.

On the other hand, if the 2nd app is talking to a printer (or anything else) via a web service, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just have the 1st app use that web service to print directly. Is there a particular reason you need a background app to perform this function?

Comment: This will allow others vendors to say hey I want this to work with my specific printer or device. Our main app can stay the same and the pseudo device drivers can be swapped out.  I didn't downvote you.

Comment: There is an app WebDav (approved by apple) which does this. It acts as an HTTP server via opening a local socket connection the only thing required is the other app to know its port address.

Comment: Kunal -- how does it keep the socket open in the background? My understanding is the only way to keep a server socket open in the background is for processing incoming VOIP calls. What background modes does WebDav register for that enable it to keep the socket open?